# How to create an fmap that can take a tuple of functions instead of just a single function?

Tags: haskell, category-theory

This could be a way of constructing

Is there a (ideally standard) way of accomplishing

```
 f :: Int -> Int
 f x = 2*x
 g :: Int -> String
 g x = show x
 h = (f, g)
 fmap h 5 -- results in: (10, "5")
```

In general, for functions going from A->T_i for some variable types T_i and a fixed type A, I think this would just be a simplification of a [BiFunctor](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Bifunctor.html), at lease for a 2-tuple of 1-argument functions - it would be great to see a generalization going beyond 2-tuples.

Comment: @chepner thanks, fixed, i think

Comment: if you want a generalization, you'd need heterogenous lists, assuming you have `(a -> b_1, a -> b_2..., a -> b_n) -> a -> (b_1, b_2,.., b_n)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `uncurry (&&&)`, as follows:

```
> import Control.Arrow
> f :: Int->Int ; f x = 2*x
> g :: Int->String ; g x = show x
> h = (f, g)
> uncurry (&&&) h 5
(10,"5")
```